# add 2 fragment in the layout android

Tags: java, android, fragment

how can I add a 2 fragment in the layout

I was able to add one fragment but adding 2 fragments in one screen always giving me an error.

Here is the code I used

```
      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
      bundle.putString("bussStopCode", bussStopCode);
      bundle.putString("bussStopName", bussStopName);
      Fragment fragment = new FragmentMainClass();
      Fragment fragment2 = new FragmentMainClass();
      fragment.setArguments(bundle);
      FragmentTransaction fragmentManager = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
      fragmentManager.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
      fragmentManager.add(fragment2,"lawl");
      fragmentManager.commit();
```

I want to put them on the relative layout but I dont know how

here is the fragment class

```
public static class FragmentMainClass extends Fragment{
    public FragmentMainClass(){}

     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_searched_data, container, false);
         TextView sn = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.stop_name);
         TextView sc = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.stop_code);


         return rootView;
     }


}
```

Comment: Why you want to load same fragment in single layout ? Post your error which you are getting ?

Comment: In fragments you can only add the single fragment at a time. To add multiple fragment you need to load it in separate layouts then only it will be visible.